# Show search results on RecyclerView using CursorAdapter,CursorLoader

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cursoradapter, android-cursor, android-cursorloader

I have a RecyclerView which loads data from the database using CursorLoader, CursorAdapter, ContentProvider and all that stuff. It is properly showing the data. But what I want is a search functionality where user types and the RecyclerView's data changes accordingly. I have done it before but with CursorLoader I'm not able to do.
I'm thinking of firing another Loader with different Id? Is it a good idea?

Here's the GitHub [link](https://github.com/hitanshu-dhawan/Todo) of my project.

Comment: your `RecyclerViewCursorAdapter` is really poor - use [this](https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b) instead and for search functionality setup its `FilterQueryProvider`

Comment: @pskink This Adapter looks more advanced than mine...thanks for that :) Can you also give a short example or good link of how to setup `FilterQueryProvider`

Comment: like always: `setFilterQueryProvider` - or, as an alternative solution, you can directly override [runQueryOnBackgroundThread](https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b#file-cursorrecycleradapter-java-L229) method

Comment: @pskink thankyou so much ... it worked like a charm :)